# jquery .change overridden by .blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form where the input elements initially are a light blue, and I wanted the following:
a) when you focus on them they become white
b) when you blur off them they return to the original blue ONLY IF the content was changed.

I had the following code:

```
$(":text, select, textarea").change(function() {    
                        $(this).css("background-color", "white");
                    });
                    $(":text, select, textarea").blur(function() {  
                        $(this).css("background-color", "white");
                    });
```

This didn't work because the .blur overrode the .change and changed back to blue regardless if the input was changed. How can I avoid this and accomplish what I am trying to do? 
The only way I had figured it out was to take out the blur and use a css :focus to make it change to white when focused on (and the .change dealt with it when it leaves focus), but the problem is that :focus doesn't work for IE7 and I would like to make it do so. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

change is for when the value changes, not the focus. Do you want:

```
$(":text, select, textarea").focus(function() {    
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
});

$(":text, select, textarea").blur(function() {    
    $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
});
```

instead?

Comment: and .change() only fires on select elements

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should've used `focus` instead of `change`.
Second, to change the original background to blue only if the value is changed, you'll need to store the old value inside a variable. And then, when the element is blurred check the value again and see if it matches the old one. If not, change the background color.

Have a look at the javascript code.

http://jsfiddle.net/rsqqL/1/

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the two answers above did what I want. For both of them, if I clicked out of the input box it turned blue regardless if I had any input in them or not. But, I modified the last answer and got the result I needed:

```
$(":text, select, textarea").focus(function() {    
$(this).css("background-color", "white");
$(this).blur(function(){
    var newVal = $(this).val();
    if (newVal == '')
    {
        $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
    }
    else
        { $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    }    
});
});
```

Comment: If this is the solution to your problem, then you should mark it as the answer so future readers will know what fixed it for you.